# How to alter a table using SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, smo

I'm using SMO to create table dynamically in Sqlserver 2008.now I would like to add new columns for existing table using SMO, but I'm trying to execute the code the finally getting run time exception as **"alter fail to table"**.My code snippet as

```
 public static bool Altertable(DynamicTable dynamicTable)
        {

            if (myDatabase.Tables.Contains(dynamicTable.Name))
            {
                Table myalterEmpTable = myDatabase.Tables[dynamicTable.Name];

                var collist = new List<Column>();

                foreach (var item in dynamicTable.Columns)
                {
                    Column col = myalterEmpTable.Columns[item.Name];
                    if (col == null)
                    {
                        Column cols = new Column(myalterEmpTable,  item.Name , DataType.UserDefinedDataType(item.Type));
                        cols.Nullable = item.IsNullable;
                        cols.Default = "";
                        collist.Add(cols);
                    }
                }
/*Here I'm getting newly added columns only*/


                foreach (var item in collist)
                {
                    myalterEmpTable.Columns.Add(item);
                }
                try
                {

                   myalterEmpTable.Alter();
                }
                catch (SmoException ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }
}
}
```

Finally I'm getting exception as **"alter fail to table"**.even googled also no help ..So my question is, what is the best way to do this using C#?

Comment: The full exception or an executable example would help

Comment: You may have problem with datatype, Just ensure the you have that datatype or try with other built in datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help..

I solved it as changed my database connection string initialization part.then it's working fine..

```
 string connns = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"];
                SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"]);
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connns);
                string password = builder.Password;
                string userid = builder.UserID;
                ServerConnection smoConn = new ServerConnection();
                smoConn.ServerInstance = sqlConn.DataSource;
                instanceServer = new Server(smoConn);
                instanceServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
                instanceServer.ConnectionContext.Login = userid;
                instanceServer.ConnectionContext.Password = password;
                projectDatabase = instanceServer.Databases[sqlConn.Database];
```